# Since $i=-1/i$, can we write $i=-1/(-1/(-1/\cdots))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, recursion

I am having an argument with a colleague about $i$, the square root of $-1$. My argument goes as follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
i &= \sqrt{-1}\\
i^2 &= -1\\
\frac{i^2}{i} &= -\frac{1}{i}\\
i &= -\frac{1}{i}
\end{align*}
$$

and then through substitution, since both sides are defined and not variables,
$$\mathrm{i} = \frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{\dots}}}}$$

Is this still equal to $\sqrt{-1}$? I argue that it does, although this would mean that there is *some* real correlation to imaginary numbers.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please always write formulas like this in MathJax...

Comment: Just as in real numbers, a square root is not unique.

Comment: Also, what's the problem?  $i = - \frac{1}{i}$ is true.

Comment: The expression $i=-1/(-1/(-1/\cdots)$ is not true. The sequence $a_1=-1$ and $a_n = a_{n-1}/(-1)$ does not converge as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: @Seeker Square roots can be defined for negative numbers just fine.  It just needs to be understood that the square root which allows any complex inputs is a technically different function than the square root which allows only for non-negative real inputs.

Comment: Yes, $i = -\frac 1i.$  But be careful with the "ad infinitum."  What holds for the finite, does not necessarily hold for the infinite.  Not sure why you think this proves some "real correlation to imaginary numbers" or even what you mean by that statement.  Imaginary numbers are numbers and are just as "real" as a real number, in that they are useful mathematical objects and describe phenomena in the real world.  But, they are not "real numbers" as that is a specfically defined set.

Comment: One way to see that the last "expression" cannot be $i$ is by seeing that *exactly the same logic applies to $-i$*. ($\frac{-1}{-i}=-i$). So $-i$ would be equal to the same expression, giving you a fake proof that $i=-i$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is true that $i = \dfrac{-1}{i}$

It is also true that $i = \dfrac{~-1~~}{~\left(\frac{-1}{i}\right)~}$

Further, it is also true that the sequence $a_1 = i$ and $a_{n+1}=-1/a_{n}$ will equal $i$ for all values of $n$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = i$ as it is simply a constant sequence.  That is to say... if you imagine your tower of division "*from the bottom up*" then yes, it will equal $i$ as you suggest.  That is... if you prefer $(\dots/(-1/(-1/(-1/i))))$

The problem is that this is not how $-1/(-1/(-1/(-1/(\cdots))))$ is generally interpreted.  The way you have written it makes it sound as though we are considering this fraction as being defined "*from the top down.*"

Any time we are dealing with an infinite number of operations or the like, we must be very clear how we are defining what it is we are looking at and this is generally done by way of sequences and limits of sequences.  If the limit of the sequence converges to a number we can say the expression "equals" that number. The way you have this written now, it makes it sound as though we are considering $b_1 = -1$ and $b_{n+1}=b_n/(-1)$... that each time we consider "*more*" of the tower of divisions, we are doing so by taking what we already have as the numerator and then dividing with something additional as the denominator.  In such an interpretation of what you have written, this sequence does not converge.  Instead, it will alternate between the two values of $-1$ and $1$.  Since this does not converge, that makes the expression you wrote undefined.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your writing was correct up to the point where you introduced $(-1)/((-1)/((-1)/\cdots))$.

The problem with this "expression" is that *it does not have a value*, thus we cannot even *ask* if its value is $i$.

This comes from the following consideration: in calculus, we normally assign values to infinite expression only if those expressions are *limits* of some sequences that *converge*. For example, we *do* say that $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\ldots=2$ because this infinite sum is, as a convention, taken as a *limit* of the sequence of the finite sums:

$$1=2-1$$
$$1+\frac{1}{2}=2-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=2-\frac{1}{4}$$
$$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}=2-\frac{1}{8}$$

etc., which obviously get closer and closer to $2$ as we add more terms.

Nothing *like* that seems to apply to your expression. In the best case, you are looking at whether the following sequence has a limit:

$$-1=-1$$
$$\frac{-1}{-1}=1$$
$$\frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{-1}}=-1$$
$$\frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{\frac{-1}{-1}}}=1$$

and so on... which is in fact the sequence $-1,1,-1,1,\ldots$, which oscillates forever and does not converge to any number at all.